# REST API endpoint for elasticpress autosuggest

Tags: ajax, rest-api, endpoints

The AJAX, which is part of Elasticpress, looks like this

```
$.ajax( {
    url: epas.endpointUrl,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    crossDomain: true,
    data: JSON.stringify( query )
} );
```

Additionally I registered my endpoint

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function ( $data ) {
    register_rest_route( 'elasticpress', '/autosuggest/', [
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'ep_autosuggest'
    ] );
} );
```

The callback looks like this

```
function ep_autosuggest( $data ) {
    // Elasticsearch PHP Client
    $client = ClientBuilder::create()->build();
    $params = [
        'index' => 'index',
        'type' => 'post',
        'body' => $data
    ];
    $response = $client->search( $params );
    return $response;
}
```

The different parts work as they should. I'm struggling with getting the data from the passed object. Any ideas?

Comment: What data? You're already passing data with the `jQuery.ajax` call. What other data do you want to send, and at what stage?

Comment: Is it being sent correctly, have you checked your browser's dev tools?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After some inspecting the [WP_REST_Request](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rest_request/), it turned out, that the `get_body()` method was the one I'm looking for. Anyhow, this is what I ended up with:

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function() {
    register_rest_route( 'ep', '/as/', [
        'methods' => \WP_REST_Server::CREATABLE,
        'callback' => 'ep_autosuggest',
    ] );
} );
function ep_autosuggest( WP_REST_Request $data ) {
    // Elasticsearch PHP Client
    $client = ClientBuilder::create()->build();
    $params = [
        'index' => 'ep-test',
        'type' => 'post',
        'body' => $data->get_body()
    ];
    $response = $client->search( $params );
    return $response;
}
```

For anyone interested, I made a plugin out of it:

https://github.com/grossherr/elasticpress-autosuggest-endpoint

Comment: Hi @nicolai - wondering if your plugin is up to date? I am following your example for the endpoint url after installing but I simply get "{"code":"rest_no_route","message":"No route was found matching the URL and request method","data":{"status":404}}" each time.

Comment: https://www.example.co.uk/wp-json/elasticpress/autosuggest/

Comment: @wharfdale I haven't really dealt with the issue in about a year, so I'd say it's probably not up to date.

Comment: Anyone got this to work in 2019 with ElasticPress > = 3.2.1?

Comment: The above code is not working.. it breaks when it reaches the ClientBuilder.. does anyone have a recent example that actually works on the latest versions?

Comment: @scooterlord I'm no longer maintaining this, maybe this is helpful to you https://github.com/grossherr/elasticpress-autosuggest-endpoint/issues/12#issuecomment-580247406

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the plugin Nicolai! Just wanted to point out a couple of things that weren't clear to me:

Once the plugin is installed, modify ep_autosuggest() in elasticpress-autosuggest-endpoint.php:

```
$params = [
    'index' => ep_get_index_name(), // get name of ES index dynamically
    'type' => 'post',
    'body' => $data->get_body()
];
```

Then, use http(s)://yourdomainname.com/wp-json/elasticpress/autosuggest/ (or whatever is specified in register_rest_route()) as the endpoint URL in the admin / ElasticPresss / Autosuggest / Settings.

Comment: Update - you don't have to modify `ep_autosuggest` anymore. I created a [pull request](https://github.com/grossherr/elasticpress-autosuggest-endpoint/pull/7) that has been merged into master. Now, these updates are included in the plugin!

Comment: Does this still work for you and if so, which versions are you using of ElasticPress and ElasticSearch? I always get error messages about ep_get_host() or ep_get_index_name(), no matter what I try.

Comment: I haven't worked on this in a while, the only thing I know is that the ElasticPress plugin version is 2.7.0. What helped me while debugging issues is actually stepping through the code with Xdebug and seeing where it fails. Maybe try that?